# Trouble loading .png file using LibGDX Gdx.files.internal

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to load a Texture to libGDX and I'm getting a file not found exception.

Here's the code that's trying to load the .png file.

```java
//Textures
private Texture tiles;
private TextureRegion grassImage;
private TextureRegion dirtImage;
private TextureRegion stoneImage;

//Entities
private Texture entities;
private TextureRegion playerImage;

public WorldRenderer(World world, boolean debug) {
    this.world = world;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    this.camera.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH/2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f, 0);
    this.camera.update();
    this.debug = debug;
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    loadTextures();
}

public void loadTextures() {
    tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tiles.png"));
    grassImage = new TextureRegion(tiles, 0, 0, 32, 32);
    dirtImage = new TextureRegion(tiles, 0, 64, 32, 32);
    stoneImage = new TextureRegion(tiles, 64, 0, 32, 32);

    entities = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("entities.png"));
    playerImage = new TextureRegion(entities, 0, 0, 32, 32);
}

public void render() {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    drawGrass();
    drawDirt();
    drawStone();
    drawPlayer();
    spriteBatch.end();
    if (debug) {
        drawDebug();
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: tiles.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
    at com.mr.zen.level.WorldRenderer.loadTextures(WorldRenderer.java:62)
    at com.mr.zen.level.WorldRenderer.<init>(WorldRenderer.java:58)
    at com.mr.zen.screens.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:29)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at com.mr.zen.Zen.create(Zen.java:12)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: tiles.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:132)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:586)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 12 more
```

The problem exists in the loadTextures() method.  Can't find the file

```
 tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tiles.png"));
```

I've made sure to put the .png files in the assets folder of the android project files.  I have no idea what's causing this; I've gotten this to work on other projects but this time around something went awry.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: make a data folder inside assets folder and keep tiles.png in data folder .Then use tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.png")); Thats how i used to do it

Comment: If you are trying to run this on desktop then you have to put the png in desktop project as well. As far as running on android is concerned. Everything is looking fine.
Try importing the png in photoshop and export it again and then use it. Sometimes this also solves problem.

Comment: many a times what happens is when u export a png due t photoshop error libGdx cant read it. This happened with me too.Try to save pngs from some other P.C. this happens all the times with me

Comment: @KaptnKrunch, are you using intellij or eclipse? if you are using intellij, you need to set the working directory of desktop to point to the android assets folder.

Comment: In case someone has the same stupid problem like me, I was trying to use some assets I downloaded and they were saved with uppercase extension, since a lot thing can cause this problem I decided to share what was mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solving the "Couldn't load file" issue by cleaning the project (Eclipse)

(For this solution is expected that the paths to your image files are correct.)

Sometimes I have this **Couldn't load file** problem when I add new images to my project. I don't know why, but my Desktop version of my LibGDX game doesn't update the folder **Mygame-desktop/bin/data** with my new images (which were added to **Mygame-android/assets/data**) when the project is built. (That is, every time I save a file, Eclipse builds the project, cause I set the option **Project > Build Automatically**.)

It should work, cause in LibGDX the Desktop and HTML projects have a link to the Android project assets folder. So, I was not suppose to need to copy manually my new images to **Mygame-desktop/bin/data**.

The solution, on Eclipse, is to clean (menu **Project > Clean...**) all LibGDX projects you use for your game, then the files in **Mygame-android/assets/data** will be copied to **Mygame-desktop/bin/data** properly.

Comment: I think I am missing some understanding on your solution, do I also need to copy the assets on the project-core folder?

Comment: @NeonWarge, no, you don't need to copy them. Your assets stay only on the android assets folder. When you use the option **Clean** on Eclipse, then your files will be somehow linked and refreshed to all your LibGDX platforms automatically.

Comment: @NeonWarge, be aware that the **data** folder that used to be created by default by the LibGDX project creator is not created anymore on latest LibGDX's versions. My examples above show this folder, so be aware.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Gradle, click the left mouse button in package explorer on `Aassets -> Gradle -> Refresh All.`

That's it =)

Answer (score 3):

create new folder **data** in the assets folder of the android project
and then access the file using **Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.png")**

`tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.png"));`

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem for me, but why does it require to have "data" folder inside the "assets" folder for android to work? It seems this is not needed for Desktop or iOS. I think it wasn't mentioned in the docs that we should have a "data" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make a data folder in the assets folder and instead of using

```
tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tiles.png"));
```

try this:

```
tiles = new Texture("data/tiles.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the left mouse button in Package Explorer on Refresh or just F5.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue working in android studio 2 using the current libgdx version.  When I save as a png in psp - cs6 and/or cs15 - it can't read it.  I can't recall the exact error message, something like io can't read stream.  So I tried saving it again in corel paint.  Same problem.  Then with the simple paint utility packaged with windows.  No good.  Finally I downloaded paint.net.  Now my workflow just involves an extra step.  Any png generated with psp, etc., pretty much any png libgdx grumps about, I load into paint.net, hit "save" and I'm good to go.

Not really a solution per se, but gets the job done.

Looks like you're good but I hope this helps someone out there.
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PNG profile is not supported by LibGDX.

I set it to `sRGB-elle-V2-srgbtrc.icc` (with Krita) and now it works.

In Krita go to:

> Image > Properties > Profile